# Retrieve next to last date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, max

I think this is a simple problem but I cannot find an easy answer. I need to retrieve the last 2 entries by date. I have used max() to get the latest date; but do not know how to retrieve the next most recent.

The stored procedure code for latest date is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Date=(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Table);
```

So using a separate procedure how do I get the next most recent?

Comment: do you need 1 record or 2? your main title says "next to last date" which means 2nd max (1 record), and as per your explanation you need the top 2...

Comment: I can easily retrieve the most recent date and have that sproc built. So I need only the 2nd most recent. I was going to write separate sprocs.

Comment: Ok tried and both of these work. I will use the code that just retrieves the next most recent date. The trick was the "Order By" this sorts the data as needed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order by` and `top`:

```
select top 2 t.*
from t
order by date desc;
```

Comment: User seems to want the next most recent. Not the two most recent.

Comment: @scsimon . . . That is not how I interpret the question "but do not know how to retrieve the next most recent.".

Comment: That’s fair @GordonLinoff and it’s how I read it initially until I studied it closer

Answer (score 0):

Or just to get the next most recent only as you stated...thus returning only one row...

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
where t.date != (select max(date) from table)
order by date desc;
```

or...

```
with cte as(
select
   t.*
   ,row_number() over (order by t.date desc) as RN
from table t)

select *
from cte
where RN = 2
```

Comment: this approach might not return what he wants if there's multiple rows with the `max(date)`.

Comment: @Beth the second one wouldn’t since I didn’t use with ties and the first wouldn’t because I use top 1

Comment: commenting on the first one, not the second (which is equivalent to the other answer.)  If the `max(date)` for two rows is the same value, they'll both be excluded by your `!=`, no?

Comment: The second is not equivalent. Gordon returns 2 rows.